# Why does `zip` take `n` sequences rather than a sequence of sequences? Shouldn't `unzip` be the main (and only) function with a similar semantics?

Tags: functional-programming, language-agnostic

`zip` is a *standard* functional-style sequence processing function that turns `n` sequences into a sequence of `n` sequences.<sup>1</sup>

`unzip` is a slightly less common function<sup>2</sup> that does something similar: it turns a sequence of `n` sequences into `n` sequences of sequences.

The two functions are very similar, in fact they can be trivially implemented in terms of each other:

`zip(seq1, seq2, ..., seqN)` equals `unzip([seq1, seq2, ..., seqN])`
`unzip(sequences)` equals `zip(*sequences)`, where `*` expands a sequence into function arguments.

---

I'm wondering why `zip` is the *main* one of these two functions, since some facts make me believe `unzip` should be the main one (and `zip` isn't needed at all):

1. `zip` requires variadic functions in order to support an arbitrary number of sequences `n` (see <sup>1</sup>). `unzip` doesn't.

   Many languages don't support variadic functions. Implementing a variadic function requires extra syntax and is often tougher than implementing one with a fixed arity.
2. `unzip` can be chained together with all the other sequence processing functions (`[...].filter(…).take(…).unzip().map(…)`), while `zip` cannot (`zip( *[...].filter(…).take(…) ).map(…)`).

Is there a story behind this?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>: in some implementations `n` is always `2` (e.g. [Haskell's](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:zip)), but these usually also offer other functions to handle `n=3`, `n=4` etc.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>: python, for instance, doesn't have it; besides the name seems to imply `unzip` derives from `zip` rather than the opposite.</sub>

Comment: This isn't really an answer per se, so I'm leaving it here. Part of it is *language*, `unzip` implies that there is a `zip` to undo, i.e. that `zip` is primary and `unzip` is secondary. It may be no more complicated than that and you certainly make a good case for your point of view vis-a-vis composition.